# How to fix layout when targeting android sdk 33 on an existing app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tiramisu

My app was working just fine until I started targeting android sdk 33. Now on devices running android 13 (sdk 33) my layouts are completely destroyed. On android 12 and lower everything looks fine. Here is the image of my layouts before and after. Does anyone have any idea whats going on and how to fix it?

[image]